# How can I convert array to string in hive sql?

Tags: arrays, string, hive, concatenation, hiveql

I want to convert an array to string in hive. I want to collect_set array values to convert to string without `[[""]]`.

```
select actor, collect_set(date) as grpdate from actor_table group by actor;
```

so that `[["2016-07-01", "2016-07-02"]]` would become `2016-07-01, 2016-07-02`

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Use `concat_ws(string delimiter, array<string>)` function to concatenate array:

```
select actor, concat_ws(',',collect_set(date)) as grpdate from actor_table group by actor;
```

If the date field is not string, then convert it to string:

```
concat_ws(',',collect_set(cast(date as string)))
```

Read also this answer about alternative ways if you already have an array (of int) and do not want to explode it to convert element type to string: [How to concatenate the elements of int array to string in Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40982183/2700344)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, you may need a JSON formatted list, so you can simply use:

```
SELECT CAST(COLLECT_SET(date) AS STRING) AS dates FROM actor_table
```

PS: I needed this but found only your question about array to string conversion.

Comment: In which version of Hive does it work? In 1.2 and 2,3,6 it says cast can only work with primitive types