# How to concatenate the elements of int array to string in Hive

Tags: arrays, hive, concatenation, hiveql

I'm trying to concatenate the element of int array to one string in [hive](/questions/tagged/hive).

The function `concat_ws` works only for string arrays, so I tried `cast(my_int_array as string)` but it's not working.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to transform using /bin/cat:

```
from mytable select transform(my_int_array) using '/bin/cat' as (my_int_array);
```

Second option is to alter table and replace delimiters:

```
1) ALTER TABLE mytable  CHANGE COLUMN my_int_array = my_int_array_string string;
2) SELECT REPLACE(my_int_array_string, '\002', ', ') FROM mytable;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the easiest way is to write a custom UDF to perform this specific task:

```
public class ConcatIntArray extends UDF {
   public String evaluate(ArrayList<Integer> in, final String delimiter){
       return in.stream().map(u-> String.valueOf(u)).collect(Collectors.joining(delimiter));
   }
}
```