# How to cast array<int> to string in hive?

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a column of type `array<bigint>` (say of value [1,2,3,4]), and I want to convert it to `string` (say "1,2,3,4"), how can I do that?

I tried `concat_ws(',' arr)`, but it complains

```
Argument 2 of function CONCAT_WS must be "string or array<string>", but "array<bigint>" was found."
```

Is there a way to cast `array<bigint>` to `array<string>`?

Comment: may be your answer is here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40977674/how-to-concatenate-the-elemets-of-int-array-to-string-in-hive

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to concatenate the elemets of int array to string in Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40977674/how-to-concatenate-the-elemets-of-int-array-to-string-in-hive)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select xx,concat_ws(',',collect_set(cast(element as string))) as arrystr
from table
lateral view explode(arr) b as element
group by xx
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select
    regexp_replace(string_with_brackets,'\\[|\\]','') as final_str
from
(
    select 
    transform(array_of_int) using '/bin/cat' as (string_with_brackets)
)
```

Comment: hhhh, I find my own solution here