# hive sql transform big int array to string array

Tags: sql, hive

I am trying to convert an array of big ints into string array in hive SQL

I've tried using

```
concat_ws
```

but that gave me an error

```
Argument 2 of function CONCAT_WS must be "string or array<string>", but "array<bigint>" was found.
```

I tried using

```
transform(mycolumn) using '/bin/cat' as mycolumn_as_string
```

It gives an error of

```
 cannot recognize input near 'transform' '(' 'mycolumn' in selection target
```

How can I convert this bigint array into an array string?

Comment: where are you using `concat_ws` here?

Comment: I tried using it before but you cant use concat_ws with a bigint it gives an error

Comment: please show us 1) table schema and 2) the hive query that is getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your table looks like this:

```
tb_name mycolumn
------- --------
tblname [111,222,333]
tblname [1234,123456,3423]
```

Then below query will not work because concat_ws only accepts string or array of string:

```
select tb_name, concat_ws('-', mycolumn) from mytable;
FAILED: Argument 2 of function CONCAT_WS must be "string or array<string>", but "array<int>" was found.
```

Based on this SO: [How to concatenate the elemets of int array to string in Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40977674/how-to-concatenate-the-elemets-of-int-array-to-string-in-hive)

Incorrect:

```
select concat_ws('-', transform(mycolumn) using '/bin/cat') as mycolumnstr from mytable;
FAILED: ParseException line 1:22 cannot recognize input near 'transform' '(' 'mycolumn' in select expression
```

Correct:

```
with tbl as (select transform(mycolumn, tb_name) using '/bin/cat' as (mycolumnstr, tb_name) from mytable) 
select concat_ws('-', tb_name, mycolumnstr) from tbl;
Result:
tblname-[111,222,333]
tblname-[1234,123456,3423]
```