# How to convert Hive array<Int> type to Vertica varchar on exporting data

Tags: arrays, hive, vertica

I have a table in Hive db with array type column which I want to copy it with content to Vertica db. The Version of Vertica db is v9.0.1-0 and I cant create table with array type. To copy table I tried to use

```
COPY vertica_schema.destination FROM hive_table_path ON ANY NODE ORC;
```

but got an empty table. Could you help me copy table and covert Hive array int type to Vertica varchar type? For example Vertica varchar values can be look as: `[1, 1, 1]` or `{1, 1, 1}`.

Vertica destination table init:

```
CREATE TABLE vertica_schema.destination (
    col_a     INTEGER NOT NULL,
    col_array VARCHAR(200), -- ARRAY[INTEGER] not working
) ORDER BY id
UNSEGMENTED ALL NODES;
```

Hive source table init:

```
create table source
(
    col_a int,
    col_array array<int>
) stored as orc;

insert into source  select 1, array(1, 2, 3);
insert into source select 2, array(2, 2, 2);
insert into source select 3, array(3, 3, 3);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try a different approach.

First create a stage table in `Hive` like

```sql
CREATE TABLE dest_stage(
    col_a INT,
    col_array array<INT> 
) STORED AS ORC;
```

Second load dest_stage with source table

```sql
INSERT INTO TABLE dest_stage SELECT col_a,col_array FROM source;
```

Third step would be convert col_array of type `INT` into col_array of type `STRING`, you can follow this link for that task

[How to concatenate the elements of int array to string in Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40977674/how-to-concatenate-the-elements-of-int-array-to-string-in-hive/40982183#40982183)

And the final step would be load `vertica_schema.destination` from dest_stage.

Answer (score 2):

Explode array, cast elements and collect into array of string (load into staging table if necessary):

```
select s.col_a,
       collect_list(cast(e.element as string)) as string_array
  from source s
       lateral view outer explode(s.col_array) e as element
```