# Converting int array to string in hive/impala

Tags: arrays, hive, hiveql, impala

I tried to `concat_ws(string delimiter, array<string>)` solution provided in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38711201/how-can-i-convert-array-to-string-in-hive-sql). 
However I am getting an error:

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ClassCastException null
```

The below statement does work, however you aren't able to select more than two columns other than the array column:

```
with tbl as (
  select transform(mycolumn, tb_name) using '/bin/cat' as (mycolumnstr, tb_name) 
  from mytable) 
select concat_ws('-', tb_name, mycolumnstr) from tbl;
```

Comment: Transformation script has to take care about other columns. It's not possible to add column separately using transform(). Read this: https://andreyfradkin.com/posts/2013/06/15/combining-hive-and-python

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked, when other columns are included in the transform