# Remove characters [ ] and ' with hive hql

Tags: sql, hive, hql

How can I clean a column using Hive HQL containing this type of string

```
["A","B","C"]
["ABC","RFG","ERD","BAC"]
```

in order to get only the values inside `" "` separated by the `,`?

**Desired output**

```
A,B,C
ABC,RFG,ERD,BAC
```

I've tried to use `regexp_replace`:

```
regexp_replace(s_agr.sig_tecnologia,'["\]\[]','')
```

but I'm receiving this error below:

```
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10014]: Line 53:1 Wrong arguments '''': No matching method for class org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFRegExpReplace with (array<string>, string, string). Possible choices: _FUNC_(string, string, string) (state=42000,code=10014)
```

Comment: Not sure if hive supports this syntax for the translate function, but try `select translate('["ABC","RFG","ERD","BAC"]','"[]','')`

Answer (score 3):

How about `replace()`?

```
select replace(replace(replace(col, '"', ''), '[', ''), ']', '')
```

Answer (score 2):

I've solved the problem with [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38711201/how-can-i-convert-array-to-string-in-hive-sql).

The problem is because I was using `collect_set` to generate all those values together and they were of type `array of strings` not `strings`.

If I then use `concat_ws(',',collect_set(column))` my problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below -

```
select regexp_replace(s_agr.sig_tecnologia, '\\[\\"\\]', '')
```